# Failed to upload Excel data to database

Tags: asp.net

I have developed an ASP.NET website which uploads an Excel file and puts its data in the database. This works perfectly on my system but when I run it on the server, it fails.  I didn't get any error message. The page is showing the error `"Server Error in '/' Application."`  when I upload the Excel file.  The file name reached the upload folder. Its name is entered in the database, but data fails.
Thanks in advance.

The code showing error:

```
    string excelConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + xlspath + ";extended properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
    excelConnection.Open();
    OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [sheet$]", excelConnection);
    OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
    string name = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string Customer = "";
    string DPS = "";
    string FSC = "";
    string FFSC = "";
    string FFSR = "";
    string DPC = "";
    string RAG = "";
    string Comments = "";

    while (odr.Read())
    {
        Customer = valid(odr, 0);
        DPS = valid(odr, 1);
        FSC = valid(odr, 2);
        FFSC = valid(odr, 3);
        FFSR = valid(odr, 4);
        DPC = valid(odr, 5);
        RAG = valid(odr, 6);
        Comments = valid(odr, 7);
        insertdataintosql(name, Customer, DPS, FSC, FFSC, FFSR, DPC, RAG, Comments);
    }
    excelConnection.Close();
    Label2.Text = "File Uploaded Sucessfully";
    Label2.Visible = true;
```

Comment: If you use remote desktop connection to the server and call this from the localhost in the browser there, you should get the error details, or set your web.config for remote errors: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>`

Comment: You should be clear in what help you are needing.  I ASSUME you need help with figuring out how to resolve the error you're getting, but you didn't (and couldn't) provide the detailed error message.  So, my advice is when you're posting a question, give no doubt to the readers what help you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, we don't know what the error is (obviously).  The first step would be to get the detailed error.  Here are a couple ways to do that:

Probably the easiest way to find out exactly what the error you're receiving is to do what the comment above me says to do about the web.config and customErrors mode="Off", OR, and this is what I do, install ELMAH (http://code.google.com/p/elmah) onto your app. You simply grab the package from NuGet OR manually add the elmah.dll (and make some simple web.config modifications, defined in the URL I just gave you). This will let you then navigate to http://www.yourwebapp.com/Elmah.axd which will show you a complete list of ALL unhandled exceptions and their details.

Of course, you want to go through the basic configuration of ELMAH first to have it work properly. But, start to finish, probably takes 10-15 minutes to set up and if you're feeling ambitious, you can set up a SQL database specifically for storing all of these errors, or by default, the app will write the errors in XML format to your App_Data folder. It really is a lifesaver and this is something you don't have to remove once you added it to your project.

Here's a link to a live site I've implemented ELMAH on: http://quikcapdev.capworx.net/Elmah.axd.

Keep in mind, all of this is just to get the detailed error.  Once we have the detailed error, then we will be able to properly answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Yeronimo...for the suggestion <customErrors mode="Off"/>.